# View Controller containment vs direct view manipulation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I am developing an iOS 5 application with the following visual structure:

[image: view containment]

where each square is a separate view. The blue views will be created dynamically (their number, the subviews, the logic behind of responding to the events). I was wondering which approach is better:

- Creating different instances of BlueViewController and adding them as child view controllers to the rootViewController or
- simple adding different views to the view hierarchy without creating the BlueViewController class and manipulating the views directly via the rootViewController

What are the pros and cons of both approaches?

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on what they do. If they are merely views then you should just be adding views to the view hierarchy. E.g. if they are just showing some sort of info, then all you need is a view. If you do it this way, I would still recommend that you use a custom UIView subclass that handles your yellow views inside them and the layout.

If however, you find that each of them need to be doing quite a bit of "controller logic" e.g. handling complex algorithms and calculations then you should implement them as controllers.

Hope this is of help to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, both are possible solutions, with pros and cons, and the right choice depends on the behavior of your app.

Using BlueViewControllers requires more lines code, but I think it is the best solution if you want different behaviors and you like well organized approach.

On the other side, adding YellowViews directly to the rootViewController could be easier, especially if your app doesn't have many views and an elaborate architecture.

In general I prefer the first approach, because, even if your project doesn't require BlueViewControllers at the moment of its development, it should help with future updates.